# Read tab-separated file in Hadoop using Python

Tags: python, hadoop

I have a tab-separated file containing information about the profile of customers.  I need to access different columns to do some data audit reports like range of values, group by etc.  I would like to use Python to write my MapReduce programs.  I need to read the input files and compute column stats such as count, max, min, etc.  For example, in the following case I need to find the maximum of col2:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
A A1 2 4 5 
B B1 3 5 8
C C1 4 5 8
```

Also note I am new in Hadoop and trying to learn how to write programs for it in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will simplify your data to get to the core of Hadoop processing.  Suppose you have the following columnar data:

```
2 4 5
3 5 8
4 5 8
1 4 5
5 5 8
0 5 8
```

scattered across *n* `data*.csv` files, and you want to get the sum of each column.  In a real-world case, of course, you will have a much larger number of rows and/or columns.  We're going to use [Pydoop Script](http://crs4.github.io/pydoop/tutorial/pydoop_script.html) to solve the problem (yes, I'm on the dev team).  Save the following code to a file named `colsum.py`:

```python
def mapper(_, v, writer):
    for i, x in enumerate(v.split()):
        writer.emit(i, x)

def reducer(k, values, writer):
    writer.emit(k, sum(map(int, values)))
```

Save your data to HDFS and run the application:

```
$ hadoop fs -mkdir input
$ hadoop fs -put data*.csv input
$ pydoop script colsum.py input output
```

Your output should look like this:

```
$ hadoop fs -cat output/part*
2   42
0   15
1   28
```

The first column stores original column indices, while the second one has the sums.  You can use this to easily reconstruct the final sum vector or leave it as it is for further processing.

Comment: Thanks @simleo ... So basically what you are suggesting that to read this files I need to write script inputing each line as a line , parsing it using seperator then do the count , max etc .

Comment: I'm suggesting that you do what's written in the answer

Comment: Thanks again for the help .....I have done that just trying to understand how hadoop read file in general so that I can transform my codes in python to do data audit of hdfs file . ...

Comment: Hadoop feeds the Mapper a stream of (key, value) records. By default, in each record, the value is a line of text and the key is its byte offset with respect to the beginning of the input file.